# Adaptador WiFi USB 300 Mbps with TP-LINK TL-WN822N not working properly

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb

I've an `Adaptador WiFi USB 300 Mbps` and `TP-LINK TL-WN822N` connector and it works but it gets blocked suddenly, I don't know why and is not always the same, sometimes 1 hour sometimes more. How can I solve this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behaviour with a TL-WN821N. I notice it only happens when I use something that floods my net, like amule or an unthrottled scp. I'm on 12.04 but this would happen sometimes on Arch too (but more rarely - in fact, the unthrottled scp on Arch was almost guaranteed to freeze my wifi).

In this state, iwconfig hangs without any response.

I have to unplug and replug the usb wifi to have the net reattempt connection. Connection is usually established then within seconds.